# Get object id after POST to API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app which connects to an API, and allows you to create audits. After I create a new audit, I need to redirect to the "show" view for that audit. How can I retrieve the ID of the newly created audit so I can pass it to my audits_path? Here is my code:

audits_controller.rb:

```
def create
  payload = params.to_json
  rest_resource = RestClient::Resource.new("#{API_BASE_URL}/audits.json")
  begin
    rest_resource.post payload, :content_type => 'application/json'
    redirect_to audits_path(???)
  rescue Exception => e
    redirect_to audits_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Hopefully that REST call returns something useful, in which case you'll need to dig out the `id` value from it and pass that through to `audits_path`. It's not clear from your example what format the response comes in as, so you will need to investigate. As another note, be careful when [rescuing everything](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html), that's bound to lead to trouble, and instead list exceptions you're expecting the `RestClient` to produce.

Comment: I think you should ask for an answer from server.

Comment: would you please post the server response from the POST request?

Comment: How do I access the server response? Sorry, just learning.

Comment: can you tell us what does `rest_resource.post payload, :content_type => 'application/json'` return? I think all the required info should be there

Answer (score 1):

In doubt try assign a variable like  `deb = (rest_resource.post payload, :content_type => 'application/json')` and `puts deb` after, see if response contains id, if yes pass to audits_path: `redirect_to audits_path(id: xx)`

Comment: I tried this: `response = rest_resource.post payload, :content_type => 'application/json'` and this is the response that is being returned:   `{"id":61,"date":"2015-01-27","household_id":2,"created_at":"2015-01-27T17:36:20.191Z","updated_at":"2015-01-27T17:36:20.191Z"}` , but I still cannot figure out how to pass the id from that. I tried `redirect_to audits_path(response[:id])` but that didn't work

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I had to parse the response first. Thanks for your help!